# In VQE, what ansatz would be best used for a maximally entangled $n$-qubit $H$?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, entanglement, vqe

What ansatz would be best used for a maximally entangled n qubit H? I came across this question in the Qiskit textbook and I really don't know how I would answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are given a Hamiltonian $H$ that can be represents with $n$-qubit, and promised that the ground state of $H$ is close to a maximally entangled $n$-qubit state, then we can use the fact that the maximal entangled $n$-qubit state $|\psi\rangle$ can be represent as:
$$ |\psi \rangle = \dfrac{|0\rangle^{\otimes n} + |1\rangle^{\otimes n}  }{\sqrt{2}}$$
which can be created by using the circuit of the form:

[image]

here I created the state $|\psi^5 \rangle = \dfrac{|0\rangle^{\otimes 5} + |1\rangle^{\otimes 5}  }{\sqrt{2}} $ but you get the idea of how to create such a state for arbitrary $n$ qubit system.

Since we are promised that our state is near this state, you can create your Ansatze (parametrized circuit) based of the circuit above, and you can add a few additional rotation gates if you wish. For instance, something like this:

[image]

Or if you think the coefficients might be imaginary, then you can add another rotation to your Ansatze, says the $R_Z$ rotation and have something like this:

[image]

You can create these circuit quite easily through the [Qiskit's TwoLocal circuit library](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.TwoLocal.html#qiskit.circuit.library.TwoLocal).  Within it, there is an option on selecting the type of "entanglement" you want to have for your Ansatze. There a few options, "Linear" or "Full" or "circular"... so you can use these pre-defined option as well. This way you don't have to worry about setting the CNOT gates by yourself.

Note that if your state is indeed the maximal entangled state $|\psi^5 \rangle = \dfrac{|0\rangle^{\otimes 5} + |1\rangle^{\otimes 5}  }{\sqrt{2}}$ then all the angles will be $0$ or very close to it, except the first angle $a[0]$, which will be $\pi/2$.